# Preventing SWT Browser Elements from Receiving Mouse Clicks

Tags: java, browser, swt, mouseevent

I'm working with the eclipse SWT toolkit, and I'm trying to use it to create a browser window that only passes mouse clicks to the underlying document conditionally (I want to stop Flash and Javascript in the page from getting clicks). I'd like some way of doing one of:

- Examining mouse events as they come in, and only passing them on to other listeners based on conditions I specify.
- Removing all listeners from a window, and only putting back the ones I want.

Are either of these possible?

Answer (score 1):

Browser, like other SWT components, have addMouseListener method. So you could implement your own listener a pass only which one you want.

[see javadoc of browser](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/package-summary.html)

**Edit**

According to your request, there could be two possible ways to do it.

First, you could use listening of events from JavaScript in browser (there is no way to avoid JavaScript if you work with html pages). If you know that you will have Mozilla browser render core (you have to install XUL Runner), you could use JavaXPCOM, but that's big unknown for me.

[snippet - listen for DOM mousedown events with javascript](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet303.java?view=co)

Second, you can call Java functions from JavaScript (again, handle onclick event, and then decide on Java, if you don't want to use JavaScript for it).

[snippet - call Java from JavaScript](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet307.java?view=co)

But frankly both ways are more ugly-er that proposed way by pure JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't do anything about the listeners that are included in the Browser by default (edited original post to clarify my intentions).

Comment: So it could be done by some javascript code, which will manage onclick method on elements where you are concern about..

Comment: Yeah it could be, and that very well might be the final implementation, but it's inconvenient given the current code base. I'd really prefer an option at the Shell or Browser level if possible, as it would be cleaner.

Comment: Yeah, but you are about to work with content of the page in browser, and SWT just use system browser to load a page. JavaScript implementation seems to be the easiest way to do it.